# Epoch 1/5 training seems to get stuck without progress

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to train my own model for image recognition and I chance upon Jason Brownlee tutorial on training a model, I made some adjustment myself to training more than 1 class and I got stuck when the training starts as there is no progress on the first epoch. below is my code. My current dataset is only 32 photos of car and bicycle all in JPG format and has been annotated. Hope I can get some help and if you need more information I would be glad to provide it.

below is the minor adjustment that was made from the original

```
class ModelDataset(Dataset):
    # load the dataset definitions
    def load_dataset(self, dataset_dir, is_train=True):
        # define class
        lines = []
        with open('OpenLabeling-master/main/class_list.txt') as f:
            lines = f.readlines() 
        count = 1
        for line in lines:
            self.add_class("dataset", count, line)
            count += 1
        # define data locations
        images_dir = dataset_dir + '/images/'
        annotations_dir = dataset_dir + '/annots/'
        # find all images
        for filename in listdir(images_dir):
            # extract image id
            image_id = filename[:-4]
            # skip bad images
            if image_id in ['00090']:
                continue
            # skip all images after 150 if we are building the train set
            if is_train and int(image_id) >= 150:
                continue
            # skip all images before 150 if we are building the test/val set
            if not is_train and int(image_id) < 150:
                continue
            img_path = images_dir + filename
            ann_path = annotations_dir + image_id + '.xml'
            # add to dataset
            self.add_image('dataset', image_id=image_id, path=img_path, annotation=ann_path,class_ids=[0,1,2])
 
    # load all bounding boxes for an image
    def extract_boxes(self, filename):
        # load and parse the file
        root = ElementTree.parse(filename)
        boxes = list()
        # extract each bounding box
        box_class_list = list()
        for box in root.findall('.//bndbox'):
            xmin = int(box.find('xmin').text)
            ymin = int(box.find('ymin').text)
            xmax = int(box.find('xmax').text)
            ymax = int(box.find('ymax').text)
            coors = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
        # extract image dimensions
#       for name in root.findall('.//name'):
#           box_class_list.append(name.text)
        width = int(root.find('.//size/width').text)
        height = int(root.find('.//size/height').text)
        return boxes, width, height
 
    # load the masks for an image
    def load_mask(self, image_id):
        # get details of image
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        # define box file location
        path = info['annotation']
        # load XML
        boxes, w, h = self.extract_boxes(path)
        # create one array for all masks, each on a different channel
        masks = zeros([h, w, len(boxes)], dtype='uint8')
        # create masks
        class_ids = list()
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            box = boxes[i]
            print(box)
            row_s, row_e = box[1], box[3]
            col_s, col_e = box[0], box[2]
            if i == 0:
                masks[row_s:row_e, col_s:col_e, i] = 1
                class_ids.append(self.class_names.index('Car'))
            else:
                masks[row_s:row_e, col_s:col_e, i] = 2
                class_ids.append(self.class_names.index('Bicycle'))
        return masks, asarray(class_ids, dtype='int32')
```

my config are as follows

```
Configurations:
BACKBONE                       resnet101
BACKBONE_STRIDES               [4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
BATCH_SIZE                     1
BBOX_STD_DEV                   [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
COMPUTE_BACKBONE_SHAPE         None
DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES        100
DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE       0.7
DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD        0.3
FPN_CLASSIF_FC_LAYERS_SIZE     1024
GPU_COUNT                      1
GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM             5.0
IMAGES_PER_GPU                 1
IMAGE_CHANNEL_COUNT            3
IMAGE_MAX_DIM                  1024
IMAGE_META_SIZE                15
IMAGE_MIN_DIM                  100
IMAGE_MIN_SCALE                0
IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE              square
IMAGE_SHAPE                    [1024 1024    3]
LEARNING_MOMENTUM              0.9
LEARNING_RATE                  0.001
LOSS_WEIGHTS                   {'rpn_class_loss': 1.0, 'rpn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_class_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_mask_loss': 1.0}
MASK_POOL_SIZE                 14
MASK_SHAPE                     [28, 28]
MAX_GT_INSTANCES               100
MEAN_PIXEL                     [123.7 116.8 103.9]
MINI_MASK_SHAPE                (56, 56)
NAME                           trained_cfg
NUM_CLASSES                    3
POOL_SIZE                      7
POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE        1000
POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING         2000
PRE_NMS_LIMIT                  6000
ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO             0.33
RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS              [0.5, 1, 2]
RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES              (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)
RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE              1
RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV               [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD              0.7
RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE    256
STEPS_PER_EPOCH                100
TOP_DOWN_PYRAMID_SIZE          256
TRAIN_BN                       False
TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE           100
USE_MINI_MASK                  True
USE_RPN_ROIS                   True
VALIDATION_STEPS               50
WEIGHT_DECAY                   0.0001
```

code to prep the model for training

```
model = MaskRCNN(mode='training', model_dir='./', config=config)

model.load_weights('mask_rcnn_coco.h5', by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc",  "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])

model.train(train_set, test_set, learning_rate=config.LEARNING_RATE, epochs=5, layers='heads')
```

Comment: If by stuck you mean your model isn't futher improving then it might be because you have a really small dataset.

Comment: Just a comment, you should look at using Yolo for this task, it will give you much better results, you also will not need to train. Just use the default model to detect the objects. 32 images is too few to train on

Comment: i will be training with more pictures later on but I would need the model to work first, I might try to get more photos to see the results

Comment: Anyway just for context i saw this issue with other people as well so the epoch is just stuck at Epoch 1/5 and the notebook Is still running, i have tried the different solution but as of now i still cant solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work and the epoch started working. the issue was with the code that was edited, I have shown a sample of the code changes I did. it somehow didn't append the coordinate inside the extract_boxes method which cause an infinite loop during the print statement.

```
    # load all bounding boxes for an image
    def extract_boxes(self, filename):
        # load and parse the file
        root = ElementTree.parse(filename)
        boxes = list()
        # extract each bounding box
        box_class_list = list()
        for box in root.findall('.//object'):
            name = box.find('name').text
            xmin = int(box.find('./bndbox/xmin').text)
            ymin = int(box.find('./bndbox/ymin').text)
            xmax = int(box.find('./bndbox/xmax').text)
            ymax = int(box.find('./bndbox/ymax').text)
            coors = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, name]
            if name=='Car' or name=='Bicycle':
                boxes.append(coors)
        width = int(root.find('.//size/width').text)
        height = int(root.find('.//size/height').text)
        return boxes, width, height
 
    # load the masks for an image
    def load_mask(self, image_id):
        # get details of image
        y = 1
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        # define box file location
        path = info['annotation']
#       print(path)
#       print("_____")
        # load XML
        boxes, w, h = self.extract_boxes(path)
#       print(boxes)
        # create one array for all masks, each on a different channel
        masks = zeros([h, w, len(boxes)], dtype='uint8')
        # create masks
        class_ids = list()
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            box = boxes[i]
            row_s, row_e = box[1], box[3]
            col_s, col_e = box[0], box[2]
            if i == 0:
                masks[row_s:row_e, col_s:col_e, i] = 1
                class_ids.append(self.class_names.index('Car'))
            else:               
                masks[row_s:row_e, col_s:col_e, i] = 2
                class_ids.append(self.class_names.index('Bicycle'))
        return masks, asarray(class_ids, dtype='int32')
```